# show proof of limits of functions using the Epsilon-Delta Definition of a Limit

Tags: limits

[prove the following function using the Epsilon-Delta Definition of a Limit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qV2w7.png)

limit of (3x^2-3x) / (x-1) =3 as x tends to 1

in the image i show my working but stuck somewhere

| f() – (3)| <

| (3^2- 3)/( −1 ) − 3 | <

| (3^2 − 3)/( −1 )− 3 | <

| (3^2− 3)/( −1 )− 3 | <

| (3^2− 3) - 3(x-1)/( −1 )| <

| (3^2− 6 +3 /( −1 )− 3 | <

Comment: Consider the alternative problem:  What is the limit as $x \to 2$ of $$\frac{x^2 - 4}{x - 2} = \frac{(x - 2)(x + 2)}{x - 2} = (x + 2).$$

Comment: [Here's](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) MathJax tutorial.

Comment: Re my previous comment, note that the formal definition of the limit involves $0 < |x-a| < \delta$, **rather than** $|x - a| < \delta$.  So, the specific value at $x=a$ is not relevant to the $\epsilon,\delta$ definition of the limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remark that $$\frac{3x^2-3x}{x-1}=3x\frac{x-1}{x-1}=3x$$ for all $x\neq 1$. You want to show that
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 1, x\neq 1}\frac{3x^2-3x}{x-1}=3.$$
Let $\varepsilon>0$, then for all $x$ such that $0<|x-1|<\varepsilon/3$ (you take $\delta=\varepsilon/3$) you have
$$\left|\frac{3x^2-3x}{x-1}-3\right|=|3x-3|=3|x-1|<\varepsilon.$$